# How To Track Changes in SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I need to track changes to some tables in SQL Azure. That is, when an update or insert occurs on a certain table, I need to receive notification in a program running in Azure.

I see this article http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2976.how-to-enable-sql-azure-change-tracking.aspx but it's dated from 2011.

Can someone confirm what the latest technique is to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Azure V12 supports change_tracking and you can use it to do this.

Comment: and here is a link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-v12-whats-new/